# Redirecting or replacing old Google Site with another (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: seo, web-hosting, google-sites, static-site

My cousin has given me her old website to "redo" which is on a Google Sites template. I have separately created a static website with Ruby on Rails setup and Bootstrap but am now scratching my head on how to transition her old Google Site to this new layout (I want to keep the original domain name).

Also, the good thing about Google Sites is that when I search for her business, it pops up on the right side of the page and sometimes pops up at the top for google local search, which is obviously great for marketing/SEO.

I did read something that Google doesn't support other platforms (I think) which is why I'm wondering if I can redirect and still retain the SEO benefits.  Any resources or suggestions would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Setup your new site with new ROR template.
2. Register and verify your new domain and old one on [Google Webmaster](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/)
3. Create a custom 404 page for old domain which suggests visiting new domain.
4. Redirect your old urls to new one by a 1:1 redirection with 301, "Moved Permanently", like www.oldone.com/games to www.newone.com/games
5. Submit your sitemap of old one to Google and BIng, they will see 301 and rewrite their crawl cache.
6. Fill out [change of address](http://(301,) in Google webmaster and add new site's sitemap.

Above method is the best SEO friendly site moving method.
ps: Not exactly ROR question .

Edit: I don't really know about google pages but one of doing this would be, deploy ROR site somewhere and use iframe in google page to project it to google page.

In your google page,
    .

use options like height="100%" to cover the entire page.

Comment: Thanks, will remove the RoR tag, still new to Stack so will keep note! Will try these changes and report back

Comment: If my answer did helped you please take a second to click best answer so that can be used for helping other users.

Comment: Hi, actually, I wanted to keep the same domain name but change the layout; I realize my wording in the original post made it sound like I wanted the "new domain" to be the final domain name when really I want to keep the "old domain" but have a new layout. Do you have advice on this type of situation?

Comment: @Kumo: Check my new answer ! if it served your request then you may want to help similar questioners by selecting my answer as the best one or upvoting it.